# How to make component fill all avaible space in Windows form using Docker and Anchor properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make component to fill all available space, unfortunately it's only fill width, height stays the same. Why fill does not fill?

Windows form with one horizontal split, each part contain one TextBox that is supposed to fill all available space.
[image: Windows form with one horizontal split, each part contain one TextBox that is supposed to fill all available space]

Layout properties of TextBox.

[image: Layout properties of TextBox.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `TextBox` you have to set its `Multiline` property to True.

[image]

or

in code:

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;
```